How to have the middleware set where I am having a custom JWT method?
I tried following the docs, where it is mentioned in the advanced usage how to use the withAuth function and wrap the middleware function:
https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#advanced-usage
I have a custom JWT method, which is what is mentioned in the above link, and I tried to pass the authOptions to get the decode function too. But I always get the token as null.
{
    jwt: { decode: authOptions },
    callbacks: {
      authorized: ({ token, req }) => {
         if (!token) {
           // Debug log
           console.log("No token found in middleware");
           return false;
         }
        return true
        }
      }
}

What I tried next was to remove the custom JWT method and let nextAuth handle the creation of the JWT token based on it's own algo, and by that way I was getting the token properly. But the issue is I cannot change to that format as I need the custom format as the token is used with an external backend.
Tried scouring the internet and went through a lot of GH issues, but didn't find a solution yet. If you do find, please add some pointers.
Thank you.
